# Как положить текст фоном?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

Как можно сделать такой эффект, как бы положив фоном под углом текст, и чтобы он спускался сверху вниз? Можно ли так вообще сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ответ автору вопроса:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  transform: rotateZ(20deg) rotateY(-15deg) rotateX(15deg);
  
  user-select: none; 
}

p {
  font-size: 8vw;
  animation: xxx 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes xxx {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-200vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto velit eligendi consequuntur officia numquam ea natus minima sequi esse nihil dolorum quisquam quo, sed veniam qui deserunt delectus facere saepe, molestiae asperiores sit? Laboriosam dolore laudantium ipsam aspernatur commodi culpa molestias excepturi unde enim adipisci quibusdam quod eius illo, qui amet sapiente quasi fuga. Facere ipsum tenetur, ipsa maiores! Rerum facilis neque vel maxime at. Veniam fugit officia odio repellendus doloremque eaque, perferendis? Iure ab quasi possimus deleniti, laboriosam vero quibusdam dolorem rem quia animi quis voluptatem mollitia impedit, officia maiores saepe reiciendis, expedita nemo itaque dolorum sint. Ea, veritatis.</p>
</div>
```

Оправдать количество плюсов:

```js
const properties = document.querySelector('.properties')
const buttons = document.querySelector('div:last-of-type')
const scene = document.querySelector('.scene')
const box = document.querySelector('.box')
const values = document.querySelector('.values')
const text = document.querySelector('.text')
const copyButton = document.querySelector('.copy')

const props = {
  perspective: {
    isActive: false,
    value: 1000
  },
  rotateZ: {
    isActive: false,
    value: 20
  },
  rotateY: {
    isActive: false,
    value: -15
  },
  rotateX: {
    isActive: false,
    value: 15
  },
  animate: {
    isActive: false,
  }
}

copyButton.onclick = () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('#for-select')
  const css = `
.wrapper {
 perspective: ${props.perspective.value}px;
}

.box {
 transform: rotateZ(${props.rotateZ.value}deg) rotateY(${props.rotateY.value}deg) rotateX(${props.rotateZ.value}deg);
}`
  input.value = css
  input.select()
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + input.value);
}

properties.onclick = e => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return
  props[e.target.name].isActive = !props[e.target.name].isActive
  e.target.classList.toggle('on')
  animate()
}

values.oninput = e => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT') return
  props[e.target.name].value = e.target.value
  animate()
}


function animate() {
  const perspective =
    props.perspective.isActive ? props.perspective.value + 'px' : ''

  const z = props.rotateZ.isActive ? props.rotateZ.value : 0
  const y = props.rotateY.isActive ? props.rotateY.value : 0
  const x = props.rotateX.isActive ? props.rotateX.value : 0

  scene.style.perspective = perspective

  box.style.transform = `
  rotateZ(${z}deg)
  rotateY(${y}deg)
  rotateX(${x}deg)`

  props.animate.isActive ? text.classList.add('animate') : text.classList.remove('animate')
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');

:root {
  --color-1: #03030C;
  --color-2: #1758FF;
  --color-3: #868997;
  --color-4: #F5F5F5;
  --color-5: #BDBDBD;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 12vw 1fr 12vw;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-1);
}

button,
input {
  font-family: inherit;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  font-size: 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

input {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

label {
  word-break: break-word;
}

span {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.properties {
  display: grid;
  background-color: var(--color-4);
}

.properties button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.values {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto 1fr auto;
  background-color: var(--color-4);
}

.scene {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scene::before,
.scene::after {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background-color: var(--color-3);
  z-index: 1;
}

.scene::before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
}

.scene::after {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  background-color: var(--color-5);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.text {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 6vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.copy {
  grid-row: -2 / -1;
  padding: 4vh 0;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  color: var(--color-1);
}

.copy:hover {
  color: var(--color-2);
}

.on {
  background-color: var(--color-2);
}

.animate {
  animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="properties">
  <button name="perspective" id="perspective-toggle">perspective</button>
  <button name="rotateZ" id="rotateZ-toggle">rotateZ</button>
  <button name="rotateY" id="rotateY-toggle">rotateY</button>
  <button name="rotateX" id="rotateX-toggle">rotateX</button>
  <button name="animate" id="animate-toggle">animate</button>
</div>

<div class="scene">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">LOREM</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="values">
  <label>
    <span>perspective</span>
    <input name="perspective" id="perspective-input" type="number" value="1000">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>z</span>
    <input name="rotateZ" id="rotateZ-input" type="number" value="20">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>y</span>
    <input name="rotateY" id="rotateY-input" type="number" value="-15">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>x</span>
    <input name="rotateX" id="rotateX-input" type="number" value="15">
  </label>
  <button class="copy">copy</button>
</div>

<textarea type="text" id="for-select" class="visually-hidden"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 9):

> Смотреть на весь экран

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background: #000;
}

.obj {
  perspective-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotateY(30deg)rotateX(20deg)rotateZ(-22deg);
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-20%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-12deg)scale(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-30%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-12deg)scale(0.8);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateY(-30%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-12deg)scale(0.85);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-40%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-12deg)scale(0.9);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(-30%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-12deg)scale(0.95);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(-20%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-12deg)scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10%)rotateY(30deg)rotateX(30deg)rotateZ(-2deg)scale(0.8);
  }
}

.text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<div class="obj">
  <svg viewBox=" 0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="clip">
      <text x="170" y="100" class="text"> i am futurama </text>
      <text x="130" y="250" class="text"> I write websites </text>
      <text x="40" y="400" class="text"> love special effects </text>
      <text x="40" y="550" class="text"> want to wow effect </text>
      <text x="170" y="700" class="text"> maybe I'll do</text>
      <text x="100" y="850" class="text"> but I won't show </text>
      <text x="130" y="1000" class="text"> Because unique</text>
    </clipPath> 
  </defs>

  
  <image  xlink:href="https://proserial.net/api/media/fetch/d6/d62c8016626b7ed66158592b0056b090.jpeg?w=1700" x="0" y="0" 
         width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"
         clip-path="url(#clip)">
    
  </image>
</svg>
</div>
```