# Как реализовать данную анимацию? Желательно чистый js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, анимация, прокрутка

Интересует реализация скролл анимации, как на главном экране (первый блок) данного сайта - https://www.glia.com/
А если быть точнее: изменение контента при каждом пикселе прокрутки
(Я не ищу готового решения, мне нужна хотя бы идея)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550320/178988

Comment: Вопрос-ссылка бесполезен для базы знаний, так как сайт в будущем может измениться или перестать работать; следует уточнить формулировку и заголовок или хотя бы добавить гифку желаемой анимации, чтобы стала понятна связь вопроса с ответами.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Маленький пример. Разогреть ваш идейный аппарат.

```js
addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  const item = Math.floor(pageYOffset / innerHeight)
  document.body.dataset.item = item < 5 ? item : 'no-items'
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000vh;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: black;
}

.item {
  --sy: 0;
  
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  height: 100%;
  
  transition: 0.7s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: scaleY(var(--sy));
  
  background-color: white;
}

[data-item="0"] .item_1 {
  --sy: 1;
}

[data-item="1"] .item_2 {
  --sy: 1;
}

[data-item="2"] .item_3 {
  --sy: 1;
}

[data-item="3"] .item_4 {
  --sy: 1;
}

[data-item="4"] .item_5,
[data-item="no-items"] .item_5 {
  --sy: 1;
}

[data-item="no-items"] .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<body data-item="0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item_1">
    </div>
    <div class="item item_2">
    </div>
    <div class="item item_3">
    </div>
    <div class="item item_4">
    </div>
    <div class="item item_5">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Итоговый вариант(но не один в один)

```js
addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  const stage = Math.floor(pageYOffset / (innerHeight / 3.5))

  switch (stage) {
    case 0:
      setStage('nothing-happened')
      break;
    case 1:
      setStage('right-column-shown')
      break;
    case 3:
      setStage('item-1-shown')
      break;
    case 4:
      setStage('item-2-shown')
      break;
    case 5:
      setStage('item-3-shown')
      break;
    case 6:
      setStage('item-4-shown')
      break;
    case 7:
      setStage('item-5-shown')
      break;
    case 8:
      setStage('item-6-shown')
      break;
  }
})

function setStage(name) {
  document.body.dataset.stage = name
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 400vh;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container__column {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container__column_left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7c19dd;
}

.container__column_right {
  width: 60%;
  font-size: calc(3vw + 2vh);
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ff7ac0;
  color: #c228e8;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(90%);
}

.list {
  --list-ty-initial: 30%;
  --list-ty: var(--list-ty-initial);
  transition: 1s;
  transform: rotateZ(-55deg) rotateX(19deg) rotateY(37deg) translateY(var(--list-ty));
}

.list__item {
  --item-name-tx: 0;
  --item-icon-tx: 0;
  --item-icon-s: 1;
  --item-opacity: 0;
  --item-s: 0;
  --middle-s: 0.6;
  --middle-opacity: 0.6;
  --small-s: 0.3;
  --small-opacity: 0.3;
  --active-x: 2vw;
  --passive-x: 6vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: right;
  opacity: var(--item-opacity);
  transform: scale(var(--item-s));
}

.list__item__name {
  margin-right: 1vw;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(var(--item-name-tx));
}

.list__item__icon {
  width: calc(3vw + 3vh);
  height: calc(3vw + 3vh);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(var(--item-icon-tx)) scale(var(--item-icon-s));
}

[data-stage]:not([data-stage="nothing-happened"]) .container__column_right {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

[data-stage="item-1-shown"] .list {
  --list-ty: calc(var(--list-ty-initial) - 10%);
}

[data-stage="item-2-shown"] .list {
  --list-ty: calc(var(--list-ty-initial) - 20%);
}

[data-stage="item-3-shown"] .list {
  --list-ty: calc(var(--list-ty-initial) - 30%);
}

[data-stage="item-4-shown"] .list {
  --list-ty: calc(var(--list-ty-initial) - 40%);
}

[data-stage="item-5-shown"] .list {
  --list-ty: calc(var(--list-ty-initial) - 50%);
}

[data-stage="item-6-shown"] .list {
  --list-ty: calc(var(--list-ty-initial) - 60%);
}


/* 1 итем */

[data-stage="item-1-shown"] .list__item_1,
[data-stage="right-column-shown"] .list__item_1 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--active-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--active-x);
  --item-icon-s: 1.4;
  --item-opacity: 1;
  --item-s: 1;
}

[data-stage="item-1-shown"] .list__item_2,
[data-stage="right-column-shown"] .list__item_2 {
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-1-shown"] .list__item_3,
[data-stage="right-column-shown"] .list__item_3 {
  --item-opacity: var(--small-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--small-s);
}


/* 2 итем */

[data-stage="item-2-shown"] .list__item_2 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--active-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--active-x);
  --item-icon-s: 1.4;
  --item-opacity: 1;
  --item-s: 1;
}

[data-stage="item-2-shown"] .list__item_1 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--passive-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--passive-x);
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-2-shown"] .list__item_3 {
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-2-shown"] .list__item_4 {
  --item-opacity: var(--small-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--small-s);
}


/* 3 итем */

[data-stage="item-3-shown"] .list__item_3 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--active-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--active-x);
  --item-icon-s: 1.4;
  --item-opacity: 1;
  --item-s: 1;
}

[data-stage="item-3-shown"] .list__item_2 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--passive-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--passive-x);
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-3-shown"] .list__item_4 {
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-3-shown"] .list__item_5 {
  --item-opacity: var(--small-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--small-s);
}


/* 4 итем */

[data-stage="item-4-shown"] .list__item_4 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--active-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--active-x);
  --item-icon-s: 1.4;
  --item-opacity: 1;
  --item-s: 1;
}

[data-stage="item-4-shown"] .list__item_3 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--passive-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--passive-x);
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-4-shown"] .list__item_5 {
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-4-shown"] .list__item_6 {
  --item-opacity: var(--small-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--small-s);
}


/* 5 итем */

[data-stage="item-5-shown"] .list__item_5 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--active-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--active-x);
  --item-icon-s: 1.4;
  --item-opacity: 1;
  --item-s: 1;
}

[data-stage="item-5-shown"] .list__item_4 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--passive-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--passive-x);
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}

[data-stage="item-5-shown"] .list__item_6 {
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}


/* 6 итем */

[data-stage="item-6-shown"] .list__item_6 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--active-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--active-x);
  --item-icon-s: 1.4;
  --item-opacity: 1;
  --item-s: 1;
}

[data-stage="item-6-shown"] .list__item_5 {
  --item-name-tx: calc(-1 * var(--passive-x));
  --item-icon-tx: var(--passive-x);
  --item-opacity: var(--middle-opacity);
  --item-s: var(--middle-s);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container__column container__column_left"></div>
      <div class="container__column container__column_right">
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list__item list__item_1">
            <span class="list__item__name">Chat</span>
            <span class="list__item__icon"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list__item list__item_2">
            <span class="list__item__name">Audio</span>
            <span class="list__item__icon"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list__item list__item_3">
            <span class="list__item__name">Video</span>
            <span class="list__item__icon"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list__item list__item_4">
            <span class="list__item__name">SMS</span>
            <span class="list__item__icon"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list__item list__item_5">
            <span class="list__item__name">Phone</span>
            <span class="list__item__icon"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="list__item list__item_6">
            <span class="list__item__name">Social</span>
            <span class="list__item__icon"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Вряд ли во всей этой каше переменных можно что-либо понять, но тут та же самая идея с различными состояниями страницы как и в примере выше.

---

Основа

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  overflow: hidden;
}

.container__column {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;

  height: 100%;
}

.container__column_left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7c19dd;
}

.container__column_right {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #ff7ac0;
   
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.list {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: rotateZ(-55deg) rotateX(19deg) rotateY(37deg);
  
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__column container__column_left"></div>
    <div class="container__column container__column_right">
      <ul class="list"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1085481/355286) можно посидеть и накрутить более похожий угол наклона

Comment: однако талантливо =)

Comment: @hu-fo Замечательно, очень понравилось. Код ещё не смотрел подробно, но результат впечатляет

Answer (score 6):

Ещё один маленький пример. Рисуем контур фигуры. Для этого нам потребуется небольшой код JavaScript и фигура SVG. Атрибут `d` нам предоставит возможность определения пути для рисования.

```js
//Рисуем контур фигуры
var stack = document.getElementById('stack');
var meet = document.getElementById('meet');
var scrolling = document.getElementById("scrolling");
var length = scrolling.getTotalLength();
scrolling.style.strokeDasharray = length;
scrolling.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var scrollactive = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  var draw = length * scrollactive;
  scrolling.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}

//Запускаем событие когда доскролили до конца страницы
window.onscroll = function() {
  var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight;
  var documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight ? document.documentElement.scrollHeight : document.body.scrollHeight;
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
  if ((documentHeight - clientHeight) <= scrollTop) {
    meet.classList.add('meet__active');
    stack.classList.add('stack__active');
  } else {
    meet.classList.remove('meet__active');
    stack.classList.remove('stack__active');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
  background: lightpink;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: lightpink;
}

.meet__active {
  animation: background 1.25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    fill: url(#gradient__one);
  }
  50% {
    fill: url(#gradient__two);
  }
  100% {
    fill: url(#gradient__three);
  }
}

.stack {
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: font-size 1s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}

.stack__active {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  animation: color 1.25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    color: palevioletred;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="meet" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="scrolling" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z" />
      <style type="text/css">
        rect{fill:url(#MyGradient)}
      </style>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient__one">
          <stop offset="5%" stop-color="pink" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="lightpink" />
          <stop offset="95%" stop-color="white" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="gradient__two">
          <stop offset="5%" stop-color="lightpink" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
          <stop offset="95%" stop-color="pink" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="gradient__three">
          <stop offset="5%" stop-color="white" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="pink" />
          <stop offset="95%" stop-color="lightpink" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
</svg>
<div id="stack" class="stack">Stack Overflow</div>
```

Comment: воу, спасибо! Столько всего, аж неожиданно приятно